# C# reading in a timestamp in an excel cell, and checking to see if its not more than # days old

Tags: c#, excel, com

I have an Excel cell that contains a time stamp in this format, MM/DD/YYYY HOUR:MINUTE.

Question:
I'm trying to find a solution, to be able to check if the time stamp is 2 days old.

Currently I'm able to grab excel cell values as strings, but I'm sure I can modify to grab the cell values as objects.

This is how I grab a value

```
value = objsheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString();
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly? How to turn a string into a `DateTime` object? With `DateTime.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String dateAsString = objsheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString();
DateTime date       = DateTime.ParseExact("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", dateAsString);
Boolean isOlderThan2Days = DateTime.Now.Subtract( date ).TotalDays >= 2;
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, thanks. I will update with my results, thanks.

Comment: but aren't dates stores as numbers in Excel? In case the above does not work for you try [**CONVERTING THIS WAY**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24525234/2140173)